# Is it possible to make JSON requests using Fiddler's Request Builder?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, json

I keep getting a Request format is invalid.

Here's the raw http that gets sent:

```
POST http://x.x.x.x/ws/MyWebService.asmx/TestEvent HTTP/1.1
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {"strData":"1"}
Host: x.x.x.x
Content-Length: 4
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I think it should be more like this:

```
POST /ws/MyWebService.asmx/TestEvent HTTP/1.1
Host: x.x.x.x
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 15

{"strData":"1"}
```

And it is in the connection that you specify which server to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alxandr, I want to highlight the importance of `"charset=utf-8"`. If you want to send a request body with some parameters, content type must be like this:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

And request body should be like this,

```json
{ 
  "strData":"1", 
  "strData2":"2",
  ..., 
  "strDataN":"N"
}
```

there is no need something like `"data":{ ... }`