# Is it possible to invoke a page method (ASPX) via URL (from the browser, no ajax)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this page method (web method):

```
public partial class MyTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
    public static string Greeting()
    {
        return "Hi!";
    }
}
```

Is it possible to type `MyTest.aspx/Greeting` in the browser and get the actual string? It works via Ajax (method GET) but doesn't seem to work directly from browser (the .aspx page is returned instead).

I know about MVC / Web Api, but I cannot use them.

**Related questions:**

[Possible to invoke ASMX service with parameter via url query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006828/possible-to-invoke-asmx-service-with-parameter-via-url-query-string)

[Testing a web method (with browser/Fiddler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317016/testing-a-web-method-with-browser-fiddler)

Comment: Why use ASMX in the first place? Why not Web API?

Comment: @mason, legacy project - one of the constraints being to not reference extra DLLs (no NuGet package manager and so on). Btw, ASPX, not ASMX.

Comment: Whether it's ASPX or ASMX is really no different. The mechanism is the same. WebMethods suck. Microsoft is trying to phase them out. Why not create a generic handler .ashx? And why can't you use NuGet packages?

Comment: @mason, in a generic handler you don't have (at least rudimentary) routing and parameter binding out-of-the box. You have to parse the URI, the query string and so on. Doable, anyway. I think it is a plausible idea. Thanks.

Comment: Can you move the method into an ASMX file? Then it should work if you also add the Web.Config settings mentioned in the first link.

Comment: @greg, that would not return exactly the string, but an XML-formatted string instead: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hi!</string>`

Comment: True, also the switching to ResponseFormat.Json doesn't work. I think using ASHX like @mason suggested would be the best solution.